# Java: Simple Combination of a set of element of k order

Tags: java, combinations

I have a set of numbers `{'1','13','25','32','49',...}`, i want to calculate all possible combinations of this numbers of order k.

Esample1:

```
set = {'1','5','23','41,'54','63'};
k = 4;
```

Output1:

```
1 5 23 41
1 5 23 54
1 5 23 63
1 5 41 54
1 5 41 63
1 5 54 63
1 23 41 54
1 23 41 63
1 23 54 63
1 41 54 63
5 23 41 54
5 23 41 63
5 23 54 63
5 41 54 63
23 41 54 63
```

---

Example2:

```
set = {'a','v','f','z'};
k=3;
```

Output2:

```
a v f
a v z
a f z
v f z
```

in Java plaese.

Thank you!

Comment: This is no free homework service. Please ask a specific question about some piece of code (preferably your own code). Thanks.

Comment: tagged as homework, rollback if incorrect :)

Comment: @Bart Kiers - Check out my homepage willdohomeworkforfood.com :) (j/k)

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to find an appropriate algorithm in D.Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4, fascicle 3 - Generating All Combinations*, which can be downloaded from [his website](http://cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc3a.pdf).