# How can get the possible 3 digit combination from a number having more than 3 digits in java

Tags: java

I/p: 5278
Desired o/p: 527,278,785,852 (I manually did this).  but if number is large then its a problem.

Note: Output should be in such way that no repeated combination.(i.e  in above combination there is a number 527 its enough and I don't want it's possible combination 257 or 725, etc in output,

How can I do this? Any clue?

EDIT:One important thing input digits are unique.To be more clear  at any time input cant have the value like 1123 0r 3455.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931775/java-simple-combination-of-a-set-of-element-of-k-order

Comment: @ Ray Tayek i dont ALL possible combination

Comment: @MisterSquonk question is not clear?

Comment: I don't get it. Why don't you convert this long / int to a char[] (Long.toString) and then create your combinations. You start from the first char, then the second...etc

Comment: First of all, [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)? Remember that this is free advice from people around the world and we're not going to do your work/homework. Second, you should think in the digits/alphanumeric chars like a position of an array and build your sets by using the array indexes, making sure there's no repeated set, after that start creating your combinations and make sure you haven't used one of them.

Comment: @vnshetty : I deleted my comment. I understand now and Jerome has suggested the right direction to go. Convert the number to a `char[]` then take the characters three at a time but increment your start point on every iteration. When your loop goes to the end you need to start again (factor of 3) from the beginning.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza im working  with shift operation but i need to append first numbers to back .. im trying

Comment: @ MisterSquonk thanks im trying .. i will let u knw..

Comment: @MisterSquonk  thnks all.. i got the answer..(i think my question was little unclear... sorry for that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here some example:

```
public class Combination {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("5278");
        String str;
        int lastIndex;

        if(builder.length() % 2 == 0) {
            lastIndex = builder.length() / 2;
        } else {
            lastIndex = builder.length() / 2 + 1;
        }
        str = builder.toString() + builder.toString().substring(0, lastIndex);

        for (int i = 0; i < builder.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(str.substring(i, i + 3));
        }
    }
}
```

**Update more simpler way than above (based on conversation with [veredesmarald](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793682/how-can-get-the-possible-3-digit-combination-from-a-number-having-more-than-3-di/10794160#comment14044447_10794160))**

```
public class Combination {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] digits = Integer.toString(123).toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("" + digits[i] + digits[(i + 1) % digits.length] + digits[(i + 2) % digits.length]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Crazenezz will this work for number of any number of digits?

Comment: @vikiiii: Yes, you can try it out :)

Comment: @Crazenezz Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but this approach will not yield all combinations. For example when given "12345" it does not yield any permutation of "134", "135" or "245".

Comment: @veredesmarald, the requirement here is to print triplet of successive order.In your case, that is not (134), it will work for 123,234,...etc

Comment: @Crazenezz Additionally, for numbers with only 3 digits, it generates 2 duplicate combinations and then crashes with array index out of bounds.

Comment: @veredesmarald: Not permutation, for an example if you give "12345" the `String str` value will be `12345123`. If you see the line when the `str` has been assign value. I try insert the string value from the `StringBuilder builder` and concat with `builder.toString().substring(0, builder.length() / 2)` to get the half of the value of `builder`.

Comment: @all: I update with some checking, if the length is odd or even.

Comment: @Crazenezz I understand what you are doing, I am concerned that for any string length greater than 4, this approach only generates *some* combinations, not *all* combinations. The original question is unclear as to whether this is desired or not.

Comment: @Crazenezz It also produce duplicate values for input 12322111.

Comment: @veredesmarald, @vikiiii: let me give some example, if user input is `111` it will produce the output `111, 111, 111` the idea is loop based on the length of the user input, and will take the 2 next digit. If the next digit is already on the right most, then take the first and next digit. So the result will display duplicate combination.

Comment: @vikiiii The question states that the input has no duplicated digits, so that is not an issue.

Comment: @Crazenezz 123 will yield 123, 231, 312. These are all *permutations* or the same *combination*. The OP specifically stated that *combinations* should appear only once: "Output should be in such way that no repeated combination.(i.e in above combination there is a number 527 its enough and I don't want it's possible combination 257 or 725, etc in output". This is just an edge case when there are exactly 3 digits, not a problem with your general approach.

Comment: @veredesmarald: Yes, I agree with you. I don't know if the note is wrong or not. But, actually when I tried to make the algorithm I made based on the input and output. I think if we add the note my program will be wrong for this problem. But if the note is wrong maybe than my pattern is correct.

Comment: @Crazenezz I believe this is a simpler way to achieve the same result as you: `for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) System.out.println("" + digits[i] + digits[(i + 1) % digits.length] + digits[(i + 2) % digits.length])`

Comment: @veredesmarald: Yes, more simpler than me :-) maybe you can update your answer or if you don't mind I'll update my question based on your logic.

Comment: @Crazenezz You may as well just update yours since it has already been accepted; people are more likely to read it. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void printCombinations(int input)
{
    char[] digits = Integer.toString(input).toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < digits.length - 1; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < digits.length; k++) {
                System.out.println("" + digits[i] + digits[j] + digits[k]);                      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will get you all the unique combinations of 3 digits from your input integer. Note that this works only when the digits are unique as you have stated. If you need to build combinations of other lengths you can write a recursive function.

Sample output:

```
printCombinations(12345);

123
124
125
134
135
145
234
235
245
345
```

Comment: @alexy28 The question clearly states: "One important thing input digits are unique." The changes required to cater for this scenario would depend on if duplicate digits were allowed in the output or not. If they were not I would just distinct the input set before looping, if they were the logic would have to change slightly.

Comment: @veredesmarald ypur code works fine im using it for a game do its very hard to check all the codition and your code dint crash yet t. i already accepted answer with update.. so +1 thnks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
    Integer input = 5278;
    List<Character> digits = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for(char c : String.valueOf(input).toCharArray()) {
        digits.add(Character.valueOf(c));
    }
    int a  = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<digits.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<digits.size(); j++){
            for(int k=0; k<digits.size(); k++){
                if(!digits.get(i).equals(digits.get(j)) && !digits.get(j).equals(digits.get(k)) && !digits.get(i).equals(digits.get(k))){
                    System.out.println(++a +": " + digits.get(i) + digits.get(j) + digits.get(k));                      
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void test() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    char[] digits = Integer.toString(123456).toCharArray();
    Set<String> res = new HashSet<>();
    int i = 0;
    int m = digits.length - 1;
    while (i <= digits.length - 1 && m >= 0) {

        for (int j = 0; j <= digits.length - 1; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= digits.length - 1; k++) {

                if (digits[j] != digits[k] && digits[i] != digits[j] && digits[m] != digits[j]) {
                    res.add(digits[i] + "" + digits[j] + "" + digits[k]);
                    res.add(digits[i] + "" + digits[k] + "" + digits[j]);
                    res.add(digits[m] + "" + digits[k] + "" + digits[j]);
                    res.add(digits[m] + "" + digits[j] + "" + digits[k]);

                }
            }
        }

        i++;
        m--;
    }
    res.stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));

}
```

Comment: HI @peanutfailed - did you try the values in the OP question?   it states _there is a number 527 its enough and I don't want it's possible combination 257 or 725, etc in output,_ - it looks like the code in the answer generates all combinations, not the smaller set...

Comment: Also if you think the answer is correct please update it with some words to say how it solves the question better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

Put digits of input into List, create random generator that will return indexes of this List, form your output:

```
Integer input = 5278;
char[] digits = String.valueOf(input).toCharArray();

int numberOfTrinities = 4;
String result = "";
Random generator = new Random();
List<String> trinities = new ArrayList<String>();
while(trinities.size() < numberOfTrinities ) {
    String nextTrinity = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        nextTrinity  += digits(generator.nextInt(digits.size()));
    }
    if(isUniqueDigitsTrinity(trinities, nextTrinity)) {
        trinities.add(nextTrinity);
    }        
}
String result = "";
for(String trinity : trinities) {
    result += trinity;
}
System.out.printl("Input: " + input + ", Result: " + result);
```

We nead this to check unique digits in trinity:

```
private boolean isUniqueDigitsTrinity(List<String> trinities, String candidateTrinity) {
    for(String existingTrinity : trinities) {
        String checker = existingTrinity;
        for(char candidateChar : candidateTrinity.toCharArray()) {
            checker.replace(candidateChar, '');
        }
        if(checker.length() <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This won't work, OP needs that 527 and 752 don't get repeated.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza then he could filter his list of combinations by sum of digits

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza this is basic approach he can use. If you have read about java.util.Random it has period of repeat more than Integer.MAX. I think author of question can add some checking.

Comment: @ alexey28 thnks for your respone but result i got is Result: 887752582878 if sepearte for 3 digit then it contains duplicate digit @ Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza this is not issues, but small optimisation. Are you agree?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza why don't you show us your good code but just commented? Or it is all you can?

Comment: -1 This approach is insane! Attempting to generate combinations by randomly selecting subsets and checking for repetitions is just a wrong as using [Bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) to sort a list!

Comment: @veredesmarald it will generate to you random combination that satisfy to requerements. This is not bogosort. You don't understood difference.

Comment: @veredesmarald can you propose better random based algorithm to satisfy requerements? It is easy to do it for fixed result. What about random?

Comment: @alexey28 I think that a gumboot is the best type of shoe to drive a nail with, can you suggest a better type of shoe? It is easy to do it with a hammer, but what about a shoe? **Your entire approach is fundamentally flawed**. Your code is **longer**, your code is **harder to understand**, your code takes **more time to execute**, and your code **has bugs**. Why would I try to propose a "better" terrible solution when I could just use a *good* solution in the first place?

Comment: @veredesmarald this is just words what you say about my code. You have to point concreate place and what to change if you want me take your comments in account.

Comment: @alexey28 If someone was driving a nail with a shoe and asked you for some tips on technique, would you try to give them pointers or tell them to use a hammer instead? I cannot give you advice on specific parts of your code to improve because the entire approach is inappropriate for the problem. I can only suggest to you that random numbers are ill-suited to this task, and that you should be using a deterministic approach instead.

Comment: @veredesmarald I prefer random one. And if you cannot propose how to improve it - maybe you should not comment it?

Comment: @alexey28 If you want to continue proselytizing terrible solutions in the face of obvious shortcomings, that's your choice. Enjoy going through life hitting nails with shoes; I'll stick with the hammer.